# Are there any issues with defining main as int main(...){}

Tags: c

I have been thinking a lot about the most honest way to minimally express the main function in C(Yes, it's trivial and usually not interesting, but it's interesting to me).

For a long time, to this day, I prefer defining main as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

My issue with this is that I usually never use those arguments, so it makes the arguments explicit, even though I don't care enough about them in the code to write them out.

So I started doing

```
int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is honest, since it does not explicitly say that the function has no arguments, as many do in `int main(void){}` definition, and i'm satisfied with it.

However, I just had an idea that using variadic definition of main makes the definition of main more comfortable for me because it "looks" to me as though the function does have arguments, but I don't care about them right now.

```
int main(...)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any issue with such an abuse of notation for ...? That is, ... is meant to be used for functions of pattern (, argument from which number of following arguments can be deduced, ...). Whereas this main does not fit this pattern, and is technically a misuse of notation.

I understand the notation is misleading to other readers(... is somewhat of an advanced concept, and being abused makes it more misleading), and I will still prefer the other prototypes when sharing the code. I am merely curious on whether it is valid C to do that.

The questions I have are:

1. Is the variadic definition of main portable or is it possible that some compiler will not like it.
2. Is it generally okay to do this kind of definition, or are runtime/compile-time consequences to doing so?

Comment: Support for signatures other than `(void)` and `(int, char**)` is implementation-defined, so check with your vendor. And the code won't be portable.

Comment: Did you try `int main(...)`? If your compiler accepted that as valid, then what compiler are you using?

Comment: @user3386109 "g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2", and 
"Debian clang version 3.0-6.2 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)"

Comment: @user3386109 Now that I think more about it, I lied. I cheated and compiled it as C++. Both clang AND gcc does produce an error: ISO C requires a named argument before ‘...’ if it is parsing .c code. My file was .cpp because I felt like trying something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is *absolutely* wrong.

It is wrong because it is invalid syntax.  From n1548 section 6.7.6:

```
parameter-type-list:
    parameter-list
    parameter-list , ...
parameter-list:
    parameter-declaration
    parameter-list , parameter-declaration
```

According to the C standard, if you use `...` in function arguments, you must have at least one other argument before it.  Anything else is invalid C.  You can see from the grammar that `...` can only appear after a comma `,` and a *parameter-list*, and *parameter-list* cannot be empty.

Your compiler may accept it, but that doesn't mean much.  Compilers accept lots of things which are invalid C and happily compile them anyway.

Comment: I lied, my example doesn't actually compile as C, but rather as C++. As you have said, it is invalid C syntax, and yields an error : ISO C requires a named argument before ‘...’. This does not occur when compiling it with a .cpp extension, which I was doing for experimental reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two versions are fine. Use whichever meets your needs.

`int main(...)` would not a good signature for this function, though, even if it were valid!

`...` means that the function takes a variable number of arguments of unspecified types. Take `printf()` for example. It receives a format string followed by zero or more arguments of any type, and its function signature reflects this:

```
int printf( const char* format, ... )
```

The `main` function is not like that. It receives a specific list of arguments of specific types, not a variable number of arguments with types that must be determined at runtime.

Traditionally, `main` took two arguments as shown in your first example:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
```

Of course you can ignore those arguments by either not using them, or by defining main as in your second example: `int main()`.

Depending on the compiler/runtime, `main` may take a third argument containing the environment variables:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[], char *env[] )
```

It may even take a fourth argument on OSX:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple )
```

But in all these cases, you have specific arguments of specific types. `main` isn't like `printf` - it never takes a truly *variable* number of arguments of uncertain types. So `main(...)` is not an appropriate signature.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Different implementations of C supposedly have additional env parameter. It is required to have the first two arguments (dword, pointer) though.

Comment: Moreover, variable arguments cannot be used portably if the function doesn't have at least one named parameter.

Comment: @KerrekSB I mentioned this in my OP. This is why I am asking, it is a blatent abuse of notation, just a compelling one. It is okay to abuse notation if it is consistent and understood, we do it all the time. The issue is if there are inherent unportable/further consequences to doing this practice other  than confusing people(which is not okay, so i'd still not show it to others in  this form).

Comment: @Dmitry: Thanks! I'd forgotten about the `env` parameter - and also about the fourth `apple` parameter on OSX. I updated the answer to include those. The bottom line remains the same: even if `main(...)` happens to compile, it's *semantically* incorrect, because `...` represents an arbitrary list of arguments of unspecified types like `printf` accepts after its `format` parameter. `main` is different: it varies from compiler to compiler, but whichever one you're compiling on, there is a finite, specific list of arguments with specific types.

Comment: @MichaelGeary to be fair I see nothing preventing alternative implementations from adding 2 more arguments to main (special_counter/format, ...), and still being valid C, making main variable number of max-arguments(up to implementation limit of # of arguments a c function call can have). I mention this just for full disclosure, it is rather contrived, and unneeded, but possible.